# Retrieving children from XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, children

Helle there,
There is a post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816786/counting-nodes-in-a-xml-file-using-php
I have the same question, but instead of count, I want to echo it.
I have this code in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Row>
    <ModeNumber>1</ModeNumber>
    <Mode>online</Mode>
</Row>
<Row>
    <ModeNumber>2</ModeNumber>
    <Mode>mmorpg</Mode>
</Row>
```

And this as PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("include/gamemodes.xml");

foreach ($xml->Row->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName(), ": ", $child, "<br>";
}
```

It only echo's the first row and none more, how can I make it to echo multiple rows, the result should be:

```
ModeNumber: 1
Mode: online
ModeNumber: 2
Mode: mmorpg
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Must read in such a situation is: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the children of the first `Row` element only. Try this instead:

```
/* Iterate over all 'Row' elements */
foreach ($xml->Row as $row) 
{
    /* For each 'Row' iterate over all children elements */
    foreach ($row as $child) 
    {
        printf("%s: %s\n", $child->getName(), $child);
    }
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](https://eval.in/34653)**.